# How to test React post request

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I've created a React App that makes an AJAX post request. I'm writing some unit testing for the app using Mocha/Sinon/Chai, but I'm not sure how to go about testing this post request. I'd love to mock a test request such that the success callback for my post request is reached.

Here's my simple post request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dummyurl",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        //success callback
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.error(status, err.toString());
    }
});
```

I've looked at other answers and used Sinon's FakeServer to write something like:

```
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith(
    "POST", 
    "dummyurl", 
    [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    {"Success": true}']);

var spy_done = sinon.spy();
var spy_fail = sinon.spy();

server.respond();
expect(spy_done.called).to.be.false;
server.restore();
```

But I don't see how this is testing the post request that I've written for my app.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to hit the exact route with exact parameters to respond with the fake server. Can you show us more of your calling code? Your test does not include the component under test.

Comment: @MarioTacke I've added the post request, let me know if you need to see anything else